# Meaning of " Priceless "

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

There are so many words that have 2 opposite meaning and there is one word that I can think of is **" Priceless "**

As its " Part of speech" of priceless is **ADJ** and if you look it up the meaning on dictionary, you will find as follows.

1.) used to describe something with such a high value that its price cannot be calculated, especially because it is rare

2.) extremely funny to see or hear, delightfully amusing, odd, or absurd

First meaning express something in positive way whereas, the second express something quite negative, my questions is how do we know what it really means?

E.G.

- If someone says ***"Your car is priceless"***

What are they trying to express? In case of, we don't really hear their voice or any their expression.

Comment: My understanding is that the car, probably a vintage car, is a most valuable piece that it is difficult to estimate a price.

Comment: Thanks, but what if they tried to express in negative way, how to identify when there are 2 meaning. If the given example sentences belongs to the first meaning, then when do we use " priceless" as the second meaning.

Comment: _Price_ and _priceless_ are part of the Commercial Transaction Frame, which also includes _value, valueless, worth, worthless, cost,_ and _free_. [Their meanings are complex, but describable](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: Both examples have one meaning: extremely high value. But calling absurdity *priceless* is simply sarcasm: the meaning of the word remains while the underlying message reverses due to tone of voice. "Traffic. Great!" means that I am happy (of course not) to see heavy traffic. Traffic did not become a good thing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As its " Part of speech" of priceless is ADJ and if you look it up the meaning on dictionary, you will find as follows.
>
> 1.) used to describe something with such a high value that its price cannot be calculated, especially because it is rare
>
> 2.) extremely funny to see or hear, delightfully amusing, odd, or absurd

If you think about those two meanings, they are, in fact, aspects of the **same** meaning:

"This painting by Leonardo Da Vinci is priceless." Priceless = of such a high value that it is impossible to put a price upon **it** (the value of the painting).

"He fell into the mud! You should have seen **it**! **It** was priceless." Priceless = of such a high value that it is impossible to put a price upon **it** (the value of the  **humour-**).

Comment: Thank you, your comment give me a bigger-picture. So the value of ( Whatever ) will depend on the contexts right?

Comment: Well, if "priceless" = *something that cannot be given a price*, Then the meaning is the same in both. It thus only depends upon what you are talking about. However, the most important message is, **in English, the importance of context cannot be overstated**, meaning cannot be separated from context, and you cannot say "*In case of, we don't really hear their voice or any their expression.*" because, if there is no context, then thousands of words in English are "meaningless" or ambiguous. Consider *I don't like rock.*" The noun "rock" has several different meanings.

Comment: Yes, generally it means, it is so precious that a value cannot be assigned to it. But people who use it ambiguously (using pun), may be read in that way.

Comment: @RamPillai it is not a pun, because the word has only one meaning (beyond price). It can be used _metaphorically_ to describe a humorous situation.

Comment: My late aunt used to refer to unnecessary idiocy that way: "You said _what_? That's priceless!"